# selenium fails some times to start firefox

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am using:

- FireFox ​53.0 (64-bit)​
- selenium 3.4.1
- geckodriver-v0.16.1-linux64 (at ~/.local/bin/ which is in my $PATH)

in a python shell:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

that fails **occasionally**, it works some times, other times it fails.
here is the bug trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "..../lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py",
  line 152, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "..../lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
  line 98, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "..../lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
  line 188, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "..../lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
  line 250, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "..../lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/  
  remote_connection.py", line 464, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "..../lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/  
  remote_connection.py", line 488, in _request
    resp = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "..../.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/http/client.py",  
  line 1197, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "..../.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/http/client.py",  
  line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "..../.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/http/client.py",  
  line 266, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response
```

Comment: I tried reproducing your issue in both python 2 and 3, but in vain. Any specific points that you might be missing?

Comment: I think its "geckodriver" problem. as chromedriver works perfectly

geckodriver logs is useless

I tried to ask geckodriver to produce more logs to inspect what is happening :

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/362#issuecomment-273948335

but I still have no useful logs